# Escaping string interpolation in Dhall's multi-line strings

Tags: dhall

For example, how would I escape the interpolation in the following string?

```
let foo =
      ''
      docker login -u "$DOCKER_USER" -p "$DOCKER_PASS"
      docker build -f frontend/Dockerfile-prod \
        --build-arg OAUTH_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=${OAUTH_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID-""} \
        --build-arg OAUTH_GITLAB_CLIENT_ID=${OAUTH_GITLAB_CLIENT_ID-""} \
        --build-arg OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=${OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID-""}
      ''

in foo
```

With [non-multiline strings putting `\` in front of the interpolation works](https://github.com/dhall-lang/dhall-lang/blob/master/standard/dhall.abnf#L188-L189), e.g., replacing `"Foo ${bar}"` with `"Foo \${bar}"`, but this doesn't seem to work with multi-line strings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape `${` within a multi-line string literal by prefacing it with `''`, like this:

```
let foo =
      ''
      docker login -u "$DOCKER_USER" -p "$DOCKER_PASS"
      docker build -f frontend/Dockerfile-prod \
        --build-arg OAUTH_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=''${OAUTH_GITHUB_CLIENT_ID-""} \
        --build-arg OAUTH_GITLAB_CLIENT_ID=''${OAUTH_GITLAB_CLIENT_ID-""} \
        --build-arg OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=''${OAUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID-""}
      ''

in foo
```